# action not invoked from menuitem in jsf2.1, IceFaces3.3.0

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces-3

Am facing bit of the hurdle in displaying the page in IceFaces3.3.0 and JSF2.1.
I have "`<ice:menuItem  action="abcd" value="ABCD"/>`", this action is configured in the faces-config.xml as from-outcome and corresponding view-id is also mentioned. when i clicked menuitem it should display an page c.xhtml. But currently nothing is being triggered on click, even server log also doesnt show a single line when i click menuitem.

```
<navigation-rule>    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>    <navigation-case>                <from-outcome>abcd</from-outcome>    <to-view-id>/a/b/c.xhtml</to-view-id>          </navigation-case>    </navigation-rule>
```

pls help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the document in that link http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/MenuItem and i believe that you can't use rule directly. So, you could create a action for that redirect.